# Reset the pimefaces datatable when the search filters are cleared

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces, datatable

I have a primefaces datatable where the search filter bar is shown and hidden on the click of a button. The below javascript is being used to do the same :

`function filters() {

    var filterRow = $(".ui-filter-row");

    if (filterRow.is(":visible")) {

      $(".ui-column-external-filter").val('');

      $(".ui-filter-row").hide();

    }
    else {

      $(".ui-filter-row").show();

    }

  }`
When I am hiding the search filter bar, I am also clearing the text entered in the filter:

`$(".ui-column-external-filter").val('');`

But the datatable also should get reset or updated when the text in the filter is cleared. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

How are filtering your data because in primefaces. If you refer showcase [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableFiltering.jsf).
It is way more easy to perform.

1. `oncomplete='datatablewidgetvar.filter();'` . To perform filtering on the datatable.
2. To clear filtering you can use `oncomplete='datatablewidgetvar.clearFilters();'`.  You have to write and ajax request or some sort of event which will catch that your filters are hidden and then call widgetvar.clearFilters().